# Infragistics grid "on-demand" appearance

Tags: customization, infragistics, appearance, ultrawingrid

We're using Infragistics grid (most probably, we'll have 8.2 version at the end) and we want to configure row/cells appearances "on-demand" in order to be able to provide sort of "dynamic appearance".

For example, I want some cell to be red or green, depending on its value. We might want to tweak other characteristics as well (font, size, image, etc).

A perfect place to do it would be some event, that happen before a cell gets repainted... But it seems there is no such event in Infragistics...

Or am I wrong? Any help?

**Clarification:** I'm talking about WinForms Infragistics UltraGrid

Comment: "it seems there is no such event in Infragistics" - someone didn't do enough research.

Comment: This is a question, not my PhD thesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have finally come up with two solutions for that problem.

For some of the dynamic content we use grid elements appearance and reinitialize it "on-demand".

For the extremely resource-critical appearance we use UltraGrid.DrawFilter (see also IUIElementDrawFilter interface).

Answer (score 1):

I had to do exactly this with the IG WebGrid a few years back, and it was ... shall we say ... painful. However, the WebGrid had the advantage of a single render point -- once the HTML was emitted, we were set!

For dealing with this in WinGrid, I tried a variety of different events, both on the grid and the datasource, and met with abject failure every step of the way. The only event I got to work was `Paint`, which will likely create a performance issue.

For `Paint`, here's what I hacked together. I'm not proud of this code, and I likely wouldn't put it in production, but here it is anyway (C#):

```
private void UltraGrid1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (UltraGridRow r in UltraGrid1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (UltraGridCell c in r.Cells)
        {
            if (c.Text == "foo")
                c.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

and VB:

```
Private Sub UltraGrid1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles UltraGrid1.Paint
    For Each r As UltraGridRow In UltraGrid1.Rows
        For Each c As UltraGridCell In r.Cells
            If c.Text = "foo" Then
                c.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an event.  I don't remember exactly what it's called, but it's got to be something like 'DataRowBound' or 'ItemDataBinding', etc..

Also, [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/tonylombardo/archive/2008/01/29/demystifying-infragistics-webgrid-databinding.aspx) might help.

Not that this has anything to do with your question, but I'd stay away from heavy use of Infragistics controls - they're very heavy and will slow down the page rendering process considerably.  Just my $0.02.

Comment: I appreciate the try, but the answer wan't helpful for me and it is not related to the question. So I downvoted it, that's all.